# JPA JOINED inheritance strategy. Is it possible to make JPA instance superclass instead of resolving polymorphic type?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have a model using a Ineritance type JOINED in JPA. Currently, when other entities join with it, they get populated with instances of a child class. Is it possible to force Hibernate/JPA to stop resolving polymorphic type so if I call in another entity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
@JoinColumn(name = "parentid", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Parent parent;
```

the instance is a `new Parent(id,name)` instead of a `new Child(id,name,other)`?

Comment: if something comes back as a Parent then the database typically implies Parent. You don't post details of Parent/Child classes or what data is in the database, or what SQL is issued to retrieve the field. You always have a discriminator you could add, but that is only an optimisation

Comment: If you have a Child id=1, you are asking for JPA to return a parent instance with id=1?  What happens when you make a change to that parent instance, should the 'other' field get set to null?  What do you want to happen when child id=1 was already read, built and exists in the persistence context, should JPA requery and rebuild a Parent instance for you when it contains the same data?  What you are asking for isn't supported because it is difficult to manage reliably and quickly leads to problems when there is a simple solution: If you don't want polymorphism, don't use java inheritance.